# FFmpeg/FFplay directshow and blackmagic

Tags: ffmpeg, capture

I got a BlackMagic  intensity pro 4k capturing card, which is working fine with the express tool, I can see the live feed and record, but after I tried different stuff from what I found online to make ffplay/ffmpeg working, I ended up to have just a black screen.

I have checked if all the versions of my ffmpeg files were eanable-decklinnk, I have compiled the latest one with the latest version of the api, but still I get a black screen instead of the actually feed.

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
ffmpeg version N-77245-g7209c94 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (Rev4, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration:  --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable -libass --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame
 --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtwolame --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtesseract --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libbs2b --enable-libmfx --enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfribidi --enable-opengl --enable-libvpx --enable-libkvaza
ar --enable-libwebp --enable-decklink --enable-libgme --disable-w32threads --enable-opencl --enable-libzimg --enable-openssl --disable-debug
  libavutil      55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavcodec     57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavformat    57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 21.100 /  6. 21.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
[dshow @ 0000000ba36b6480] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 0000000ba36b6480]  "Blackmagic WDM Capture"
[dshow @ 0000000ba36b6480]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\decklink#avstream#5&2550cef9&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\decklinkcapture1"
[dshow @ 0000000ba36b6480]  "Decklink Video Capture"
[dshow @ 0000000ba36b6480]     Alternative name "@device_sw_{860BB310-5D01-11D0-BD3B-00A0C911CE86}\{44A8B5C7-13B6-4211-BD40-35B629D9E6DF}"
[dshow @ 0000000ba36b6480] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 0000000ba36b6480]  "Wej?øcie liniowe (Blackmagic Audio)"
[dshow @ 0000000ba36b6480]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{977E2DB6-B17C-4343-9018-652924C20A8C}"
[dshow @ 0000000ba36b6480]  "Decklink Audio Capture"
[dshow @ 0000000ba36b6480]     Alternative name "@device_sw_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\{AAA22F7E-5AA0-49D9-8C8D-B52B1AA92EB7}"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

The result above tells me that ffmpeg can see the card and I am able to open a communication, I have checked one post where it says you need to specific which input type is showing, otherwise it will never work, and I did that, but still no luck.

By running the command line above, I can only see a black screen but not actually errors.

I am running Windows 8.1 64bit.

```
ffplay  -pixel_format uyvy422 -framerate 25 -f dshow -i video="Decklink Video Capture"  -format x264
ffplay version N-77245-g7209c94 Copyright (c) 2003-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (Rev4, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration:  --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libass --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame
 --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtwolame --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtesseract --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libbs2b --enable-libmfx --enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfribidi --enable-opengl --enable-libvpx --enable-libkvaza
ar --enable-libwebp --enable-decklink --enable-libgme --disable-w32threads --enable-opencl --enable-libzimg --enable-openssl --disable-debug
  libavutil      55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavcodec     57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavformat    57. 20.100 / 57. 20.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 21.100 /  6. 21.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Decklink Video Capture':    0B f=0/0
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.138773, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 720x576, 25 tbr,
10000k tbn, 25 tbc
   1.51 M-V: -0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Comment: I have actually figured out that only specific mode the recording works.
FPS and pixel format has to be THE EXACTLY THE SAME, otherwise it will never work.

I had to record another camera which used uyvy422 at 59.94 FPS, and by adding the right settings, I managed to record.
I had some issues about recording raw video, due to some overmemory, even if I made the buffer the bigger I could, so I am converting on the fly to MKV.

I hope it helped someone, I will be able to post the final line later

Answer (score 0):

You must configure the capture card's hardware driver to match your source's framerate. Although with newer driver releases Desktop Video SHOULD automatically detect a framerate. I wouldn't trust it working outside the BMD proprietary Media Express app. Usually recording the uncompressed video uses less processing power because no decoding is necessary, you will however need much higher read/write disk speeds and available disk space.